# How to fix Connection Refused Error in Curl

Tags: php

I'm trying to download a xml file from url: https://www.bayzade.net/exportlink_181019170321.xml

But I cant download this with curl. Error: Connection Refused.

But I can see on url from browser. How can I fix this error?

Xampp PHP 7.

```
$fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt', 'a');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.bayzade.net/exportlink_181019170321.xml',
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_STDERR => $fp
));
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($resp);
```

Connection Refused

Comment: This indicates you're being blocked at the network level, and is not something that can be solved by PHP. Contact the site operator and ask if they have an API or other instructions on how to extract information from their site programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` to make a completely request,

some sites serve completely different content or HTML to different OS and browser versions, this is done by detecting their user agent

just including the `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` to your CURLOPT:

```
$fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt', 'a');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.bayzade.net/exportlink_181019170321.xml',
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_STDERR => $fp,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
));
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($resp);
```